# Downloading grub on blackarch linux not working

Tags: grub, uefi

I am trying to install BlackArch Linux in a virtual machine but when I try to download GRUB it doesn't work. I enter

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=GRUB*
```

when I type that in I get an error saying

```
Cannot find EFI directory
```

I don't know why it won't work. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an EFI directory. (you dont have UEFI) use the MBR instead.

Give this a go:

use: `fdisk -l`

It will show you your current setup. You will see something similar to this:

```
/dev/sdX#
/dev/sdx#
```

those entries represent partitions on your system. Your MBR is located 'outside of your partition table' so directly on `/dev/sdx`, not on any /dev/sdx#.

So that is where you want grub to install:

```
grub-install /dev/sdx
```

Hope this helps. let me know if this does the trick :)

Comment: I tried to install grub to the MBR but i got another error that says 'failed to get canocial path of airootfs'